# Referring to image file in WPF project in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2012

I'd like to load images into a WPF project with a short pathname. Details follow.

I've got a WPF solution that looks like this:

```
Solution 'GB" (16 projects)   
   ABApp
     Properties
     References
     ...   ...   
   ImageApp
     Properties
     References
     images
        mona.jpg
     App.xaml
        App.xaml.cs
     Window1.xaml
        Window1.xaml.cs
```

I want to look at the `ImageApp` project.

The `App.xaml` file looks like this:

```
<Application x:Class="GB.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         StartupUri="Window1.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

and `App.xaml.cs` simply defines the class `App` to derive from `Application`.

The `Window1.xaml` file constructs a UI, and then `Window1.xaml.cs` builds a drawing area in which various image stuff will be displayed.

Inside that C# file, to load up the image `images/mona.jpg` that I want to display, I end up writing something like this:

```
        Image myImage;

        BitmapImage myBitmapImage = new BitmapImage();

        myBitmapImage.BeginInit();
        myBitmapImage.UriSource = 
             new Uri("../../images/mona.jpg", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
        myBitmapImage.EndInit();
        //set image source
        FormatConvertedBitmap newFormatedBitmapSource = new FormatConvertedBitmap();

        newFormatedBitmapSource.BeginInit();
        newFormatedBitmapSource.Source = myBitmapImage;
        newFormatedBitmapSource.DestinationFormat = PixelFormats.Bgra32;
        newFormatedBitmapSource.EndInit();
        bmpSource = newFormatedBitmapSource;
        myImage.Source = bmpSource;
        BuildRenderTransform();
```

(I apologize for that code -- it's a kind of simplification of what's really going on, so it may not be letter perfect.)

My question is about the Uri: I have to write `../../` at the front of the Uri so that the executing program (which ends up in `ImageApp/bin/Debug`) knows it has to go up two levels and then down into the `images` folder. Is there some way that I can just write something like `new Uri("images/mona.jpg", ...)` instead? Can I tell WPF that the source directory should be used as the starting path for relative searches?

I confess, the whole Uri thing is mostly baffling to me, despite my having read the microsoft help articles and several StackExchange questions/answers..

I have the suspicion (and vague memory) that by adding something to the xaml for the project, I can make this happen, but I just can't seem to do it.

Any ideas?

Comment: You should use resources and pack URIs.  This embeds the file into the assembly instead of loading it from disk.

Comment: That seems to go against the advice in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442000/is-it-really-important-to-use-pack-uris-in-wpf-apps. Also, I tried following that advice, using a line similar to `playIcon.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"pack://application:,,,/TempApplication2;images/mona.jpp"));`, but I don't really know what name to use to replace `TempApplication2`; all the suggestions say "where you fill in the name of your assembly", but is that `ImageApp`? Or is it some other name? And if it's another name, how would I know what it is?

Comment: That advice is exactly what I'm saying.  The assembly name can be found in Project Properties, and is usually the same as the project name.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure (can not check right now), but try to specify something like this

```
new Uri("/ImageApp;component/images/mona.jpg");
```

And ensure you have ImageApp in references